# Empty label shows during validation in html-bootstrap form

Tags: jquery, css, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap

This question is purely CSS.

I am building a simple HTML contact form using Twitter Bootstrap 3. The contact form looks great. And for validating the form fields, I used Bootstrap Validator Plugin. Simple to use, easy to integrate plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/TLLe2/

This is the initial version of my form. On clicking the submit button without entering the fields, validation messages will come up.

I just wanted to highlight those fields in red which are not entered, so I used the below code & removed the validation messages from the script.

```
 highlight: function (element) {
                            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                        },
                        unhighlight: function (element) {
                            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                        }
```

Now...the new version of my form is in the following fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/XSf37/

Now on clicking the submit button..all fields are highlighted as well as no custom messages are shown. But the label that used to show the custom messages are loaded even if no messages are there.

For example....

for username field,

```
<label for="txtusername" class="error"></label>
```

is loaded...so is for every other field..This breaks my form's layout. Is there any way to remove those labels or not to load those labels????

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your validate function:

```
errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
    return true;
  }
```

The custom error placement function(see the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#errorplacement)) to stop creating blank labels.

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XSf37/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/XSf37/3/
remove error label tag from html

```
<form id="new-user-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action=""
    method="post">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="txtusername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input id="txtusername" name="txtusername" tabindex="1" type="text"
                class="form-control"> <span id="showusername"
                class="help-block"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtfname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">First
            Name*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input id="txtfname" name="txtfname" tabindex="2" type="text"
                class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtlname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last
            Name*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input id="txtlname" name="txtlname" tabindex="4" type="text"
                class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtpassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label"">Password*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input id="txtpassword" name="txtpassword" tabindex="5"
                type="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtrpassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Repeat*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input id="txtrpassword" name="txtrpassword" type="password"
                tabindex="6" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ddlgroup" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Group*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <select id="ddlgroup" name="ddlgroup" tabindex="7"
                class="form-control">

                <option value="cxvxcv">value</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-7">

            <button id="butnid" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save
                User</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think that will work,  I tried and it didn't work for me.  It probably worked in the fiddle for you because you edited the fiddle I made which is already taking care of the issue.  Removing the error label tag will not stop from creating labels for errors.  Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XSf37/4/),  I just removed the part that I added.

Answer (score 0):

Try to control the length of the error message.

errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
   if(error[0].innerHTML.length > 6){

6 is becaouse in my blank label errors was an nbsp entity